# Finding element using asterisk in HTML with VBA Excel

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to extract price from a website by using ie.doc.innertext and asterisk but its not working.

For example, the price in innertext is: "Cart Total: $25"

My condition is: If the words "Item added to the cart" exist in innertext and "Cart Total" exist in innertext, then extract the part after colon in the innertext Cart Total: $25

It's **$25** which I want.

My code is:

```
Sub GetPrice()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument


IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate " http://www.example.com"

Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = IE.Document
doc.forms("shipform").Elements("upcs").Value = "025192197925"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


doc.forms("shipform").Elements("submit").Click

Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

html_code = doc.body.innerText

If InStr(html_code, "Item added to the cart") > 0 Then

    If InStr(html_code, "Cart Total " & "*") > 0 Then
        the_string = Right("Cart Total " & "*", 15)
        MsgBox the_string
    End If

ElseIf InStr(html_code, "Item not added") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not added"
End If

Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'd highly appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Instr will treat "*" as a literal asterisk, not a wildcard, so remove that from your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim pos as Long

If InStr(html_code, "Item added to the cart") > 0 Then

    pos = InStr(html_code, "Cart Total")

    If pos > 0 Then

        the_string = Mid(html_code,pos+10, 5)
        MsgBox the_string

    End If

Else Then
    MsgBox "Not added"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the code. It works flawlessly. I also searched how MID function works but couldn't get the point in the light of my question. So what     Mid(html_code, pos+10, 5) is doing? Is it adding 10 more characters to Cart Total and then from Cart Total + 10, its giving us 5 from the right ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instr gives you the position of where "Cart total" starts, so the +10 moves past that to begin capturing after "Cart total".

Comment: Thank you for your help, explanation and time Tim. I highly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

try these to give you an idea

```
debug.print split("Cart Total: $25")(2)          ' space is the default split character
```

or

```
debug.print split("Cart Total: $25", ":")(1)
```